# SQL command not properly ended - INSERT MULTIPLE ROWS - SQL

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, sql-insert

I don´t know why SQL Developer returned "SQL command not properly ended" when i tried to add multiple rows. When i tried to insert one row, all was ok. Can somebody help me? Thanks.

````
INSERT INTO TEAMS (TEAM_ID, NAME, POSITION, PLAYED, WIN, LOSE, DRAW, GF, GA, GD, POINTS)
VALUES
    ('MUN','MANCHESTER UNITED', 2, 29, 16, 9, 4, 56, 32, 24, 57),
    ('LEI','LEICESTER CITY', 3, 29, 17, 5, 7, 53, 32, 21, 56),
    ('CHE','CHELSEA', 4, 29, 14, 9, 6, 44, 25, 19, 51);  ```
````

Comment: I _think_ Oracle only lets you insert one row at the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle require separate insert statements.  `VALUES` can only be used for a single row.  Alternatively, you can use `INSERT . . . SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO TEAMS (TEAM_ID, NAME, POSITION, PLAYED, WIN, LOSE, DRAW, GF, GA, GD, POINTS)
    SELECT 'MUN','MANCHESTER UNITED', 2, 29, 16, 9, 4, 56, 32, 24, 57 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'LEI','LEICESTER CITY', 3, 29, 17, 5, 7, 53, 32, 21, 56 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'CHE','CHELSEA', 4, 29, 14, 9, 6, 44, 25, 19, 51 FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it is working good now.